# Hibernate setParamater a class

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am new to Hibernate.

I want to create a public `Object getById(Class class,long id)` function. I tried creating query like: `from :nameEntity where id= :id` but I'm facing problems when setting parameter for `nameEntity`. Hibernate doesn't recognize it as a parameter.

I used `session.createQuery` function. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will either have to do String concatenation to achieve this:

```
session.createQuery("from " + clazz.getName() " where id=:id").
        setParameter("id", id).
        uniqueResult();
```

or use the [Criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html):

```
session.createCriteria(clazz).
        add(Expression.eq("id", id).
        uniqueResult()
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to create a public `Object getById(Class class, long id)` function. I tried creating query like:" from :nameEntity where id=:id " but I'm facing problems when setting parameter for 'nameEntity'. Hibernate doesn't recognize it as a parameter.

Don't build a query, use the `load()` or `get()` methods from the `Session`. They are actually heavily overloaded, allowing to pass the class either as `Class` or `String`, the persistent object identifier and, if required, a lock option (for pessimistic locking):

```
get(Class clazz, Serializable id)

load(Class theClass, Serializable id)

get(Class clazz, Serializable id, LockOptions lockOptions)

load(Class theClass, Serializable id, LockOptions lockOptions)

get(String entityName, Serializable id)

load(String entityName, Serializable id)

get(String entityName, Serializable id, LockOptions lockOptions) 

load(String entityName, Serializable id, LockOptions lockOptions)
```

What are the differences between `get()` and `load()`? This is explained in the Reference Documentation:

> #### [10.3. Loading an object](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-loading)
>
> The `load()` methods of `Session`
>   provide a way of retrieving a
>   persistent instance if you know its
>   identifier. `load()` takes a class
>   object and loads the state into a
>   newly instantiated instance of that
>   class in a persistent state.
>
> ```
> Cat fritz = (Cat) sess.load(Cat.class, generatedId);
>
> // you need to wrap primitive identifiers
> long id = 1234;
> DomesticCat pk = (DomesticCat) sess.load( DomesticCat.class, new Long(id) );
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can load state into
>   a given instance:
>
> ```
> Cat cat = new DomesticCat();
> // load pk's state into cat
> sess.load( cat, new Long(pkId) );
> Set kittens = cat.getKittens();
> ```
>
> Be aware that `load()` will throw an
>   unrecoverable exception if there is no
>   matching database row. If the class is
>   mapped with a proxy, `load()` just
>   returns an uninitialized proxy and
>   does not actually hit the database
>   until you invoke a method of the
>   proxy. This is useful if you wish to
>   create an association to an object
>   without actually loading it from the
>   database. It also allows multiple
>   instances to be loaded as a batch if
>   batch-size is defined for the class
>   mapping.
>
> If you are not certain that a matching
>   row exists, you should use the `get()`
>   method which hits the database
>   immediately and returns `null` if
>   there is no matching row.
>
> ```
> Cat cat = (Cat) sess.get(Cat.class, id);
> if (cat==null) {
>     cat = new Cat();
>     sess.save(cat, id);
> }
> return cat;
> ```
>
> You can even load an object using an
>   SQL SELECT ... FOR UPDATE, using a
>   LockMode. See the API documentation
>   for more information.
>
> ```
> Cat cat = (Cat) sess.get(Cat.class, id, LockMode.UPGRADE);
> ```
>
> Any associated instances or contained
>   collections will not be selected FOR
>   UPDATE, unless you decide to specify
>   lock or all as a cascade style for the
>   association.
>
> It is possible to re-load an object
>   and all its collections at any time,
>   using the `refresh()` method. This is
>   useful when database triggers are used
>   to initialize some of the properties
>   of the object.
>
> ```
> sess.save(cat);
> sess.flush(); //force the SQL INSERT
> sess.refresh(cat); //re-read the state (after the trigger executes)
> ```
>
> How much does Hibernate load from the
>   database and how many SQL SELECTs will
>   it use? This depends on the fetching
>   strategy. This is explained in [Section
>   20.1, “Fetching strategies”](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching).

How to choose between them?

> Choosing between `get()` and
>   `load()` is easy: If you’re certain the
>   persistent object exists, and
>   nonexistence would be considered
>   exceptional, `load()` is a good option.
>   If you aren’t certain there is a
>   persistent instance with the given
>   identifier, use `get()` and test the
>   return value to see if it’s `null`.

#### See also

- [Hibernate Load and Get](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/post/Hibernate-Load-and-Get.aspx)
- [Loading Entities with Hibernate](http://jpa.ezhibernate.com/Javacode/learn.jsp?tutorial=27hibernateloadvshibernateget)
- [Advantage of load() vs get()](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2387456)

#### Related question

- [Hibernate: Difference between session.get and session.load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608947/hibernate-difference-between-session-get-and-session-load)

Comment: @user198147: You're welcome. Feel free to accept this answer if you think it was helpful (the green tick below the vote counter on the left).