# Could not force hibernate to go to the database to get new object

Tags: hibernate, refresh

**Session Factory:**

```
hibernate.current_session_context_class=jta
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false
```

Transaction:
- UserTransaction is used.

`getCurrentSession()` of `SessionFactory` is used to get Session.

The problem is that I could not force the hibernate to access database to get the new values using `Session.get(...)` (it is updated outside) although I used `Session.clear()` or `Session.evict(…)` or `Session.refresh(…)`, `SessionFactory.evict(...)`.
 It always kept the old values.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you sure that transaction that updates values "outside" is comitted?

Comment: Yes, it is committed. I have tried to query it from the other SQL client.

Comment: One strange thing was that when I tried to clear() or evict(), the item was removed in the current Session according to my debug(then I committed the transaction). However when my program call "get" in another transaction, it still did not access the new one from database :-S. Any possible causes AXTAVT? - TNX!

Comment: @Cathernie: Do you understand that `get()` returns a lazy proxy and don't access the database immediately. If you need immediate access, use `load()` instead.

Comment: ASAIK get() returns the actual object and not a proxy, and load() returns a proxy and throws an exception when it can't the object in cache (if used) and database.[Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608947/hibernate-difference-between-session-get-and-session-load] @Catherine did you evict the instance of the object or the class

Answer (score 0):

session.flush() --- will flush your memory update in db.
session.clear() will clear session.

Now query again will fire on database.