# Hibernate : Why Session.load method exists in Hibernate as it throws unrecoverable exception if Object Not Found

Tags: hibernate

What is the difference between `load` and `get` methods of `Session` in Hibernate?

> load() will throw an unrecoverable exception if there is no matching
>   database row.
>
> get() will return null if there is no matching database
>   row.

Why did Hibernate Creators kept this Method load in the API? (As it throws an unrecoverable exception if the Object isn't found). Isn't `get()` sufficient?

Comment: What do you mean by unrecoverable?  Load simply throws an exception, but that can still be caught...

Comment: Un-recoverable refers to the fact that load should be used when non-existence is a serious error (use load when you know that an instance exists) i.e. it shouldn't be used to check for existence by catching exceptions, that's what get should be used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more to this that just the exception vs null return if an entity isn't found.

Load may also return you a proxy instead of a persistent instance of your entity. This proxy would then trigger the loading of this entity when a property is first accessed.

This is discussed at length on the Hibernate forums [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2387456), previously on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608947/hibernate-difference-between-session-get-and-session-load) and in plenty of other places.

Comment: Thanks Alex , the first link was very good . I still got one question here , As far as my understanding , both load and get tries to get Object from cache first , if not found then only a hit to Database is made ?? Please correct me if i am wrong .

Comment: Yes that is correct, both method will hit the first and second level caches before going to the database.

Comment: And you should use load method only in occasions that you are certain about the existent of the object